# Graphing Circles, Ellipses, Parabolas, and Hyperbolas

Tags: circles, conic-sections

I need help plotting a curve on a graph where the distance from focus1 is always the same ratio to the distance from focus2.

For instance, lets assume focus1 is -5 along the x axis, and focus2 is +5 along the x axis.

If we plot a point at +4, this point is 9 units from focus1, and 1 unit from focus2. It's a 9 to 1 ratio, or 90% along the x axis from focus1 to focus2. I would like to plot everywhere else on the graph that the ratio is 9 to 1. I imagine this will make some sort of ellipse that spills out past focus2.

If we plot a point at 0, this point is 5 units from focus1, and 5 units from focus2. It's a 1 to 1 ratio, or 50% along the x axis from focus1 to focus2. Plotting a curve where every point is equal distance from both foci will make a straight line straight up the y axis.

If it helps to describe what I'm doing in greater detail, just let me know and I would be happy to oblige.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Let the $\big(\pm a,0\big)$ be two [foci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_(geometry)). Then $~\dfrac{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{(x+a)^2+y^2}}=k.~$ For $k=1$, we have the segment's

[perpendicular bisector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerpendicularBisector.html); in this case, *OY* : $x=0$. Otherwise, after squaring and multiplying with the denominator, we get a simple circle. After all, a straight line can be interpreted as a [circle of infinite radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_circle).