# Finding the locus of a $z=x+iy$ and its radius if $|z-1|=2|z+2-3i|$

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

> If the point $P$ in the complex plane corresponds to the complex number $z=x+iy$ show that if $|z-1|=2|z+2-3i|$ then the locus of $P$ is a circle centre at $-3+4i$, and find the radius of the circle.

Putting them into cartesian equations, we have:

$$
(x-1)^2+y^2=2[(x+2)^2+(y-3)^2]\\
x^2-2x+1+y^2=2x^2+8x+8+2y^2-12y+18\\
-x^2-10x-y^2+12y=25
$$

So it seems as if the centre must be $(-5,6)$ or $-5+6i$ with a radius of $5$, but that doesn't match the correct answer ($2\sqrt2)$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In the first line the right side should be $4[...]$.

Comment: @AnuragA D'oh! When I multiply by $4$, I get a radius of $\sqrt{51}$ - is that right?

Comment: The equation you get is $3x^2+3y^2+18x-24y+51=0$. Now divide by $3$ to get $x^2+y^2+6x-8y+17=0$. Complete the squares to get radius.

Comment: @Semiclassical yep, thanks for catching

Comment: By giving a geometric interpretation to $|z-z_0|$, you will notice that [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997933) question is equivalent to yours, albeit a bit more general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to Anurag A:

$$
(x-1)^2+y^2=4[(x+2)^2+(y-3)^2]\\
0=3x^2+18x+3y^2-24y+51\\
-(x+3)^2-(y-4)^2=-8\\
$$

The centre is therefore $(-3,4)$ or $-3+4i$ and the radius is $\sqrt8$ or $2\sqrt2$.